# Moving large data from faulty disk in ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, clone

We just received a new massive server and are currently moving our VMs into it.
However one of our ESXi has a faulty disk and has some VMs that already failed a couple of times.

Currently we use scp in order to move the machines, as using VMware converter will require 3 machines instead of two (and we don't have an extra machine for that process online 24/7)

However, as for this VM I don't think that scp will manage to transfer such amount of data, we have already tried it on some dummy machine created on the faulty-disk-ESXi and it failed,

I do not want to use dd, I only wish to move the VMs (there are many on this machine, and I'm only interested in a couple of them) , so clonezilla/ghost/etc are out of the race too

I'm looking for a better, realiable, solution than scp that will transfer large amount of data w/o failing from several disk reads

I was wondering if anyone in serverfault could hint for a better solution that might succeed ?

Comment: Here is a hint for a better solution: Restore from backups

Comment: You're likely to encounter the same problems regardless of the tool or method you use, but you could try this: http://www.trilead.com/

Comment: whats the error code on the scp transfers?

Comment: resource busy or unavailable

Comment: I'd still say you DS is bad and that you'll only get garbage from it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If the VMDKs are faulty due to physical disk errors, then your data is lost.

Restore from backups.

Comment: THe VMDK aren't faulty due to physical disk errors, but I know that some reads will fail and thus make the transfer corrupt or stop at some stage. I'm looking for a better, realiable, solution than scp that will transfer large amount of data w/o failing from several disk reads

Comment: So why are they faulty ?

Comment: They are not faulty. The disk read fail from time to time when doing large scale read/writes...

Comment: I think you should make this very clear in the original question, since it indicates something is wrong in your Vm setup. I also don't see how you can blatantly contradict "However one of our ESXi has a faulty disk and has some VMs that already failed a couple of times.":)